# Sort posts by first letter in the title, not by first number

Tags: loop, sort

I have a custom post type that's used to display properties on a client website. I am sorting the posts by the title, but want to ignore any numbers included in that title.

How would I sort posts by the first letter [A-Z], not [0-9, A-Z]?

This is my current loop:

```
<section id="grid" class="project clearfix">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <ul id="project" class="clearfix">
        <?php
        // select our project post types
        $wptricckspost = array( 
            'post_type' => 'project',
            'orderby'   => 'title', 
            'order'     => 'ASC' 
        );
        // Create the new loop
        $loop = new WP_Query( $wptricckspost );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
            <li class="item">
                <header>
                    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                </header>
                <article>
                    <?php the_content();
                    // Other HTML stuff below...
```

Comment: Where would numbers go in that sort? Might make sense to simply exclude such from the set...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit messy to do in MySQL, given the lack of a `preg_replace` - the following uses a nested `REPLACE` to strip all numbers from the title:

```
function wpse167989_posts_orderby( $orderby, $query ) {
    global $wpdb;
    // Strip all numbers from title, and trim any leading spaces.
    return $wpdb->prepare(
        'LTRIM(' . str_repeat( 'REPLACE(', 10 ) . $wpdb->posts . '.post_title'
        . str_repeat( ', %s, %s)', 10 ) . ') ' . $query->get( 'order' )
        , 0, '', 1, '', 2, '', 3, '', 4, '', 5, '', 6, '', 7, '', 8, '', 9, '' );
}
```

Then

```
add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'wpse167989_posts_orderby', 10, 2 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
remove_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'wpse167989_posts_orderby', 10 );
```

EDIT per comments: to remove hyphens in addition, the filter becomes

```
function wpse167989_posts_orderby( $orderby, $query ) {
    global $wpdb;
    // Strip all numbers & hyphens from title, and trim any leading spaces.
    return $wpdb->prepare(
        'LTRIM(' . str_repeat( 'REPLACE(', 11 ) . $wpdb->posts . '.post_title'
        . str_repeat( ', %s, %s)', 11 ) . ') ' . $query->get( 'order' )
        , 0, '', 1, '', 2, '', 3, '', 4, '', 5, '', 6, '', 7, '', 8, '', 9, '', '-', '' );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bonger,
I'll test this out tonight and let you know how I get on.

Comment: Thank you @bonger, this works perfectly. would there be a way of adding a hyphen to this too. So for example if the number looks like this: 8-10 Title Here.

Comment: Yes, just change the two `10` arguments to the `str_repeat`'s to `11` and then append `, '-', ''` to the `prepare` parameters - I'll update the answer...

Comment: That makes sense, I tried to add '-', '' yesterday but didn't realise that the 10 represents the amount of arguments. Thanks once again.